# Appending Data to Uploaded File Using PHP

Tags: php, image, forms, upload, metadata

I'm making a PHP upload form, but need to add some additional data to each image based on what the user types in. For example, they choose the file to upload and type in the name, height, width, and price of that file, then hit submit. That information needs to be stored with the photo or appended to the metadata.

Here's what I have for submitFile.php:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload.php"
  method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000" />

    Select a File: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" /><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

And here's what I have for Upload.php:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = "uploads/images";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    echo "<pre style= font-size:20px>";

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile))
    {
        echo "<b>File has been successfully uploaded!</b>.\n";
    }
        else{
        echo "<b>File upload failed!</b>.\n";
    }

echo '<br/>Here is some more debugging info:'."<br/>";
echo "Name:".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]."<br/>";
echo "File Type:".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]."<br/>";
echo "File Size:".($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024)." Kb<br/>";
echo "Temp File:".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]."<br/>";

echo "</pre>";

?>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, you just need to add more fields to your form, then save them into db. Or I am not understanding what you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

For **JPEGs** (and maybe **TIFFs**?), you should use something like [this](https://github.com/lsolesen/pel/).

However, for **PNGs**, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190438/305357) answer.